# NSURLConnection's connectionDidFinishLoading before redirects

Tags: ios, url, redirect, nsurlconnection

In my iOS 5 app, I am trying to resolve redirects of a URL to its the final URL, and only then actually try to open the link in Safari.

I'm using code along these lines:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1629/_index.html

If I use a bitly link to do the redirect to the iTunes store, 'connectionDidFinishLoading' does end up getting called with my iTunes store link. Perfect.

If I instead use a redirect on my website 'connectionDidFinishLoading' is always called too early - before the redirects have resolved. That means that safari flashes up redirects a second or so later, and then the app store opens.

I don't know if i'm having a problem because my web server is just too slow?  (maybe takes 1-2 seconds)  Has anybody else bumped into this problem or have advice for how to proceed? Many thanks!

Comment: How are you performing the redirects on the server? Are the redirects handled by Apache configuration? PHP headers? Meta tags?

Comment: My redirects are done with Meta tags as I just found that to be the simplest.  Is that problematic?  Thanks!

Comment: That's what I thought. Yes, that is the issue -- the page is actually completing its load, so the event fires. You should use server-level redirects with corresponding HTTP codes (ie, 301), as meta tags actually "refresh" a loaded page -- sometimes to another page -- rather than perform an actual redirect.

Comment: A decent source of info on creating redirects via various server-side methods: http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php

Comment: Cheers VV.  I initially didn't want to walk down the road of server side because I understood that I'd be missing out on  google analytics.  Sounds like that's a different question for a perhaps a different forum though.  Thanks so much.